# How to add Coldfusion admin back on IIS

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I deleted the default website by accident and naturally I lost access to the CF administrator. I managed to put back the default site but I don't know how to add the virtual directories for CF 11 back. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run `wsconfig.exe` in `c:\coldfusion11\[cfusion]\runtime\bin\`

Answer (score 2):

I think if you include the /CFIDE into your site , then you can access the CF administrator.
Create a virtual directory with name `CFIDE` pointing to `C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE`